# How we can read Xml Response from DocuSign event Notification (DocuSign Connect Functionality) in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, docusignapi

I have try to Implement Docusign Connect Functionality. I have Enable Docusign Connect functionality. I have create Envelop and Pass the Event Notification object and also configuration is done Admin Connect 
Configuration related Setting in Docusign

[image]

When Send Mail regarding Sign in (Complete) recipient. and recipient sign in the 
document complete. It will call my configuration related url. i didn't understand 
how should i received the xml responce in my method.

Success Log Screen [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your app must include a listener HTTPS URL that DocuSign can POST to. This URL must be available on the public internet; it can’t be blocked by a firewall.

See this DocuSign blog [post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/) for setting up connect.

Comment: I have used HTTP. i have login account  Developer Sandbox. 
"HTTP  for Developer Sandbox apps."

 In My Post Method. Create File based upon received the notification from docusign connect
 Try to Analyse Request.Param. i try write log file. but i didn't get the different 
 Param so i find out xml string response in there
 So there no any firewall block my post url.

implement code

  https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp/blob/master/Webhook/Controllers/WebhookController.cs

 but i always received Request Parameter is null.(This i got from Log file)

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written to parse the connect notification. Its hard to tell what you are doing wrong without looking at your code.